# advice on browsing multiple points with leaflet - query only the points in the viewport

Tags: postgis, leaflet, carto

This a very basic question, but I don´t quite know where to start

I have a postgis table with aproximately 15.000 points hosted on CartoDB

And I'm developing an application that should let the user navigate a map, and show the points that are inside that area, with several filter applied

I was thinking about building a query like this to pass to the web service

```
select * from my_table 
where 
  ST_Contains(
    the_geom,
    ST_GeomFromText(
      'POLYGON((-71.177 42.390,-71.1776 42.3903, -71.1776 42.3903,-71.17758 42.3903))'
    )
  ) and
  [more filter conditions]
```

I just need to know the four points of the view port from leaflet, and update it everytime the user moves or zooms...

I guess this it just what the map view on cartoDB does...

Can anybody give me a hint on how to achieve it, or at least tell me if my approach is completely wrong.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. I think you may want to use [ST_Within](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Within.html) rather than [ST_Contains](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html); at the very least, you'll want to reverse the order of your arguments to ST_Contains. In the example you provided, you're asking if `the_geom` contains the `POLYGON` you specified.

To get the bounding box in Leaflet, you could try something like:

```
var b = map.getBounds(); // An instance of L.LatLngBounds
var s = 'POLYGON((';

// Build up a POLYGON WKT string
[b.getNorthWest(), b.getNorthEast(), b.getSouthEast(), b.getSouthWest(), b.getNorthWest()].map(function (ll) {
    s += ll.lng + ' ' + ll.lat + ',';
});
// Strip last comma and space
s = s.substring(0, s.length - 2)

// Don't forget the final '))'
s += '))';
```